# Switch type of Object in Java

Tags: java

So I'd like to know an easy way of switching over valid types in Java, such as below:

(I know this doesn't compile, but I want this functionality)

```
public void put(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {

    } else if (obj instanceof String) {

    } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {

    } else if (obj instanceof List<String>) {

    } else if (obj instanceof Map<String, String>) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this `obj instanceof List<String>` or this `obj instanceof Map<String, String>` will compile

Comment: Of course I don't know how you want to use your method and what would be inside the method, but isn't it easier to just create multiple `put` methods each with a different parameter type? So an `public void put(Integer integer)` that does something with the integer, and a `public void put(String str)` that does something with the String, etc. Again, it really depends on what you want to use the method for.

Comment: @JoachimSauer or even better use generics

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I've deleted my comment because Kevin basically said the same thing and explained in more detail. I fail to see how generics would help here, since presumably he won't be treating them all the same.

Comment: This seems like a bit of an x y problem. If you describe the fuller problem you're trying to solve, there's almost certainly a better solution than this approach.

Comment: Note that solution suggested by @KevinCruijssen will *not* work in your case, because methods are overloaded statically and the actual method called will *not* depend on the runtime type of your object.

Comment: @JoachimSauer since the method is called `put` I thought OP's trying to implement some sort of collection (a queue or a map)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Always be careful about *guessing* the underlying intention of the OP. Far too often, even they dont know. They have an idea how to vaguely get from A to B, but as said: be careful about guessing.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to provide 5 overloads, and push the burden onto the client to tell you the type?

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry I posted this before I went to sleep last night. I'll try to just provide 5 overloads for the put method. Someone guessed before, but the put method isn't for a collection at all.

Comment: No need to apologize! I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simply answer is: there is **no** switching on "type" in Java. In contrast to languages such as Scala, Java doesn't have an almost magic "pattern matching" feature.

When you really need to do that: figure the specific type of an Object instance, to then do different things based on the true nature of the object, such an if/else cascade is one of few choices.

One alternative is to use a map, like `Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>)` or something alike. In other words: you (upfront) create a map that knows a **method** to call for different classes, and then do `obj.getClass()` to see if your map knows about that class. But that mechanism isn't very robust, as it only uses `equals()` for the class instances.

Beyond that: there are only very few selected use cases where such kind of "type switching" makes sense. Typically, you approach this problem ... by stepping back, looking at the *real* underlying problem and designing a completely different solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible as of [Java 16 pattern matching for switch](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-pattern-matching-switch-preview)

```java
static String formatterPatternSwitch(Object o) {
    return switch (o) {
        case Integer i -> String.format("int %d", i);
        case Long l    -> String.format("long %d", l);
        case Double d  -> String.format("double %f", d);
        case String s  -> String.format("String %s", s);
        default        -> o.toString();
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm using Java 17 and this does not seem to be part of the standard yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in this way:

```
public void put(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {

    } else if (obj instanceof String) {

    } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {

    } else if (obj instanceof List) {
      List list = (List) obj;
      if(!list.isEmpty()){
        if(list.get(0) instanceof  String){
          List<String> listString=(List<String>)obj;
          //Do what  you want to do
        }
      }

    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
      Map map = (Map) obj;
      if(!map.isEmpty()){
        Map.Entry entry = (Entry) map.entrySet().iterator().next();
        if(entry.getKey() instanceof String && entry.getValue() instanceof String){
          Map<String,String> mapStrind= (Map<String,String>)obj;
          //Do what  you want to do
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: `List<String>` and `Map<String, String>` can contain null values. This way of checking for generics is unreliable (it is generally impossible, because of type erasure).

Comment: yes . it is generally impossible. but if values are not null then you can check in this way or you can add a check `value !=null` before checking the type, but in taht case you are not able to get the type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29). It returns the runtime type of the object.

Comment: where is the difference to instanceof?

Comment: @Cyril `instanceof` is faster ;-)

Answer (score -1):

No, there's none built in. Switches can only switch on integers and strings, the only other structure is `if`.

You can try a map keyed with Class objects, because for each object you can perform a `getClass()` operation and get a "token" representing its class.

More bad news: you can never find out the generic part in runtime (so you can never tell `List<String>` from `List<Integer>`), that information is just not available.

Comment: You mean: "Switches can only switch on *char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer,  Strings, or an enum*";

Comment: If you go and enhance your answer, it will be the one answering the question though.

Comment: @dbl. I meant precisely what I said. All the types you enumerated are integer types (notice I said `integer`, not `int` or `Integer`).